# SPSS K means cluster

Tags: spss, k-means

I'm working on car accident cases

1500 accident data and 33 variables

When I use k means cluster, in the Anova table i see to high F values like 5x10E5 with 0,00 significance.

And also there are some F values like -17x10E23 with same 
significance value (-17x10e23).

Why F values are so high or negative?

Answer (score 3):

The ANOVA table is to be interpreted with much caution in clustering (I often ignore it). Model assumptions for the F-test run in the ANOVA are violated in clustering, because the groups are not pre-specified but are rather chosen to minimize the sum of squares, which the F-test doesn't take into account. Therefore best advice is probably to ignore F- and p-values. By the way F-values cannot be negative by definition and chances are your negative one is the result of a rounding error (assuming that you did everything else right).